# Let $P,Q,R$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $P+Q=P+R$, is it the case that $Q=R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Effectively I'm trying to show that: $Q \subset R$  and  $R \subset Q$.
We know that $P+Q \subset P+R$ and that $P+R \subset P+Q$ and I'm really struggling to get from this to a solution. I have been staring at this problem for hours now, any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need some assumptions.  If, say, $P=\mathbb R^2$ then any $Q,R$ will work.  Or, for general $P$, take $Q=P$ and $R=\{0\}$.

Comment: And other nontrivial cases are easy to obtain such as $P$ generated by $(1,0),$ $Q$ generated by $(0,1)$ and $R$ generated by $(1,1).$

Answer (score 2):

It''s trivially false. Otherwise, it would mean that, say in $\mathbf R^2$, if two bases share a vector, the other vectors are collinear.